# DAC/AMP & 'Audio Accessory Mode' in Samsung NOTE 8

Tags: android, mode, adk, accessory

I have a Samsung NOTE 8 (SM-N9500 Android 9).

I have recently tried the [Cyrus Soundkey](https://www.cyrusaudio.com/products/soundkey/) USB DAC/AMP with it and it is excellent for music.
However, with phone calls, the Note 8 sends the audio to its built-in speaker/earpiece instead of sending it to the Soundkey. I even tried to force output to USB DAC with 'lesser audioswitch' with no success ([see video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qJWKcnmZqp0)).

In contrast, the Samsung Note 8 comes with [USB-C earphones](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0722QXJG8) which can handle both music and calls.
I am guessing that these earphones work in '[Audio Accessory Mode](https://www.soundguys.com/usb-audio-explained-18563/)' ie. analogue audio straight through USB.

If my assumption is correct :

1. Why does the Note 8 need to even use analogue output for phone calls when it can output digital audio via USB? Can't the phone call just be routed via a digital path?
2. Is there a way to disable 'Audio Accessory Mode' and force the Note 8 to use pure digital output for everything including phone calls?
3. Is there a device that can handle concurrently 'Audio Accessory Mode' and also be a DAC/AMP?

### UPDATE #1

I also tried a phone call with the Cyrus Soundkey and a Galaxy A53 (Android 12) phone and it works perfectly! The audio is routed to the DAC and the mic used is the built-in mic inside the phone.
So Soundkey is NOT the problem... it must be the android device.